# Using LIKE for a Range of Numbers

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In my WHERE clause, I'm trying to use LIKE for a range of numbers.  For example:

```
WHERE rr.sequence LIKE '05600%' 
   OR rr.sequence LIKE '05601%' 
   OR rr.sequence LIKE '05602%' 
OR rr.sequence BETWEEN LIKE('056035%' AND '056038%')
```

Otherwise, I would need to use a LIKE statement for each potential number combination between `'056035%' and '056038%'`

Comment: Cant you use `like '0560[0-9]%'` ? This translates to `05601...9`. Also, storing numbers as strings is not a good idea.

Comment: Check the length of these number-strings as '05600%' will match '056001' and also '05600999999999999'. To wit an actual [CHECK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints) may be appropriate.

Comment: Upon further review, you're exactly right.  How else would I go about filtering the Sequence range that includes:  '0560%' thru '05608985%'

Comment: Will these values all have the same number of digits? On other words, if they were all actual numbers instead of numbers-as-strings, would they all be of the same order of magnitude? Are there any business rules saying what the lower and upper values in any search could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to do the following:

```
OR rr.sequence LIKE '05603[5-8]%'
```

But in general, I agree with Kin's comment on the question: "storing numbers as strings is not a good idea".